# How do I convert a Hive interval to number of seconds?

Tags: sql, hive

I'm surprised to not find anything useful on Google for what I thought was a simple question:

How do I convert a Hive interval to seconds?

For example, say I have an interval:

`select timestamp('2020-01-03 12:34:36') - timestamp('2020-01-01 12:34:34') diff`

This returns `2 00:00:02.000000000`

Two days and two seconds.

I just want to convert this to the number of seconds contained in that result. What is the cleanest way I can convert this interval to seconds?

I've tried to add this interval to unix epoch `date '1970-01-1'` and use `unix_time` to get the number of seconds, but for some reason it returns the wrong result.

I suppose I can extract day, hour, minute, second individually and add them up.

There has to be a cleaner way, right?

Answer (score 2):

How about using unix_timestamp as below -

```
select unix_timestamp('2020-01-03 12:34:36') - unix_timestamp('2020-01-01 12:34:34') diff
```

It works fine for me. I am using version 3.1.0.3.xxx

**EDIT :** Based on the comment below, here is what you can use -

```
select unix_timestamp('02 00:00:02.000000000',"dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS") + 86400;
```

So, assuming the timestamp difference is stored in column named diff and it's in the format specified and the datatype is string, the general assignment would be as below

```
select unix_timestamp(diff,"dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS") + 86400;
```

Comment: The timestamp subtraction I did in my question was just to arrive at an interval. My table already has an interval column. Given this, preexisting, interval, I want to convert it to number of seconds.

Comment: @Shahbaz - Edited & updated my response to address the comment above.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. As far as I can tell, none of the select statements above operate on the 'interval' data type. I have no strings in my tables, only timestamps and intervals.

Comment: @Shahbaz - Wow! Wasn't aware the we can store interval datatype in a table on Hive. New learning for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve the same issue and it seems there is no clean way to do it. The best I could find is to extract seconds, minutes, hours and days and just sum it all together. As shown below.

```
cast(extract(second from diff) as bigint) +
extract(minute from diff) * 60 +
extract(hour from diff) * 60 * 60 +
extract(day from diff) * 60 * 60 * 24
```

While extracting seconds, function seems to return `double` value. Probably to express the fraction of second if needed. Since you need just seconds, you can drop the fraction, hence the cast to `bigint`.